# Diagrams for Data Flow?

Tags: database-design, workflow, diagram, dataflow

I'm a database programmer, but I have never used data flow/diagram program. I would like to explain some Data Diagram to a client. 
Question - what is a program that will allow me to easily create a diagram to explain some data tables and process (windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Visio is the most omnipresent, and it does a fair job.

I personally prefer *Enterprise Architect* or *Visual Paradigm for UML* for my diagrams. I find Visual Paradigm more user-friendly in terms of building the diagrams, but EA better for the actual presentation of the diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

I have used dia successfully and it does the job! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [draw.io](https://draw.io).

It is a **free, online Diagram/UML tool provider** and it does the job very well.

**No download required.**

**How to use it? J**ust go on the website using any Webrowser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE)and start drawing your diagram.

**Want to save your diagram ?** Once you're happy with your diagram, you can save it on your machine or on any cloud provider(Google Drive, DropBox, OneDrive).

**Want to change something on a saved diagram?** Just import it from your machine, your cloud provider or a URL and start your modifications.

**Want to export it as png? pdf? xml? whatever?** you can do that too in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visio, if you have it (or can get it). If not, some alternatives I've worked with are dia, Yed, and InSight.

Answer (score 0):

If the diagram isn't too complicated or if the tiny details don't matter that much you could also use a whiteboard, imho that always works pretty good, especially if your face to face and you can walk them through the datamodel.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some online options to do diagramming, http://creately.com/ for instance.